# spring data jpa - hibernate page requests go out of memory (1mil page size)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am pulling 1 million documents per page from a view in MSSQL for indexing.  It works fine for 3 pages and then either go out of memory or take forever! Something is not being cleared from memory. Can someone help how to clear cache after each page request? I am using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  Also, is there any more efficient way to get this data out (about 300 million rows)?

PAGE_SIZE = 1 million

```
    int i = 0;
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(i, PAGE_SIZE);
    Page<Item> page = myRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    int maxPages = -1;
    maxPages = page.getTotalPages();
    do {
        for (Item t : page.getContent()) {
        ...... processing ......
        pageRequest = new PageRequest(i, PAGE_SIZE);
        page = myRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        i ++;
    } while (i < maxPages);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to evict/clearthe session before you make another request to the db.

```
session.evict(page); // removes page instance from memory
session.clear();  //clears session when doing batch updates
```

Comment: Thanks! how to get session from LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean? I am using spring-data-jpa.